# Align Image Vertically in Email HTML Newsletter without Flexbox

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am working on a HTML email newsletter. I have the layout split up via various tables and inline CSS. If you visit https://heathology.github.io/email-newsletter/, you can see a live demo of my newsletter.

There is an image that says Fright Night and it is column 1 of two-columns. I would like to center the image vertically next to the content in column 2. I cannot get the image to bump down.

Below, you will see my css code:

```
/* two columns */
    .two-columns.last {
        padding: 15px 0;
    }
    .two-columns .padding {
        padding: 20px;
    }
    .two-columns .content {
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 20px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .button {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        color: #171a1b;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .button-dark {
        background-color: #171a1b;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

In the HTML below, you can see how I have arranged it via tables:

```
<!-- TWO COLUMN SECTION -->
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color: #26292b; color: #ffffff;">
                    <table width="100%">

                        <tr>
                            <td class="two-columns last">

                                <table class="column">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="padding">
                                            
                                            <table class="content">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <a href="LINK"><img src="img/2022-Fright-Night.png" alt="" width="260" style="max-width:260px;"></a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>

                                <table class="column">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="padding">
                                
                                            <table class="content">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <p style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;">Fright Night</p>
                                                        <p style="padding-bottom: 16px;">Do you like chills and fright? Then, join St. Auggies' youth at Frontier City's Fright Night on Friday, October 28 from
                                                        6:00pm-10:00pm. Tickets are $42.99/per person. Open to youth and adults 12 & up.</p>
                                                            <a href="LINK" class="button">Sign Up</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>

                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Are there any recommendations? If need be, you can see the full code [here](https://github.com/heathology/email-newsletter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change in css style for .two-columns .column

```
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
```

Comment: Ah. Man, I can't believe I missed that! Thank you so much.